# how to copy the content of a div to another div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to copy the single element inside a selected div to another div with jquery. But with my code copies entire division to another division..

My code is :

```
$('#image').html($('#selected').html());  //which copies entire content of #selected division
```

And the division is:

```
<div class="imgs" id="selected">
<img width="100%" height="100%" data-id="1" data-alid="1" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,">
<div class="xyz"><a href="#">Xyz</a></div>
</div>
```

I need to copy only the `img` from the `div` `imgs`

Please anyone help me ... Thanks....

Comment: maybe you want this: $('#image').html($('#selected').children(':first-child').html()); but i cant tell from the html

Comment: Have you read the documentation about jquery selectors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example that makes a copy of the *first* `img` element inside the element with the `id` `"selected"` and appends it to an element with the `id` `"image"`:

```
$("#selected > img").first().clone().appendTo("#image");
```

That uses:

- [`$()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1) to find all `img` elements that are [direct children](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) of the element with the `id` `"selected"`
- [`first()`](http://api.jquery.com/first/) to reduce that to just the first matching `img`
- [`clone`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) to clone (copy) it
- [`appendTo`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) to append it to the element with the `id` `"image"`

---

It's *well worth* spending an hour reading through the [jQuery API docs](http://api.jquery.com) beginning to end. It's amazing how much time that will save you in the long wrong.

Answer (score 0):

are you looking to select the img from the #selected div?

if so just do

```
$('#image').html($('#selected img').html());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this...

```
$('#image').html($('#selected').innerHTML());
```